# Can not run with default file index.jsp with tomcat in eclipse java servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I created a file indexServlet with url pattern different , file index.jsp a view change. I try run index.jsp but it not working. I created a new project and with same folder structruce then it is working. I don't know why.

1.index.jsp

```
<%-- views --%>
<jsp:include page="${view}" />
```

2.indexServlet.java

```
    package FPOLY.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/start")
public class layoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   
    public layoutServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    if(uri.contains("/ASM/start")) {
        request.setAttribute("view","/views/subindex.jsp");
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("view","/views/404.jsp");
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}}
```

3.errors on console

```
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:520)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:906)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:113)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:190)
```

4. errors on browser

   ```
    HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
    Type Exception Report
    Message An exception occurred processing [/index.jsp] at line [2]
    Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that 
    prevented it from fulfilling the request.
    Exception
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing 
    [/index.jsp] at line [2]

    1:
    2:

    Stacktrace:   
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServl 
    etWrapper.java:605) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.j 
    ava:488)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:383)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:331)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    Root Cause
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing 
    [/index.jsp] at line [2]

    1:
    2:
   ```

Comment: What is `"${view}"` in the JSP? What have you tried differently since the last time you asked this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71476614/can-not-run-with-default-file-index-jsp-with-tomcat-in-eclipse-java-servlet ?

Comment: I just format code , it still same errors

Comment: One more time, what is "${view}" in the JSP? The messages indicate that line 2, where you refer to it, is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I want to change view layout on brower, I just can run it with indexServlet.java and when I run index.jsp then it not working and get errors. I created a new project with same project struct and index.jsp still run . I don't why it not working with old project